# How to define TextStyle depending on a boolean value in a flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting a boolean status true or false from Api, to define whether it is active or inactive like shown bellow :

```
Align(
                                 alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                 child: Text(' ${sectorsProvider.sectorsList[index].is_active == false ?
                                   'Inactive' 
                                   :  'Active' 
                                 }',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    color: sunnyColor),
                                    ),
                                    ),
```

I want to set a TextStyle for both active and inactive.
thanks for help

Comment: If you can use `is_active` to set a different `Text`, why can't you use the same logic for `style`? You can use same ternary operator to define `style` depending on `is_active` value.

Answer (score 1):

```dart
Text('bla',
  style: sectorsProvider.sectorsList[index].is_active== true
    ? TextStyle(...) 
    : TextStyle(...),
)
```